# error RC2255: named STRINGTABLEs are not allowed - occurs when generating a Japanese RES file

Tags: c++, unicode, localization, codepages

I have a static library with several .RC files, each for a specific language.  For the most part (English, French) the project builds fine in Visual Studio (i.e. generates .RES files).  See below with regards to the en-GB.RC file I have crafted:

```
#pragma once

#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h"

/* Exceptions */
STRINGTABLE
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_UK
{
    IDS_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE_ARGUMENT, "Value is invalid."
    IDS_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE_ARGUMENT_NAMED, "'%s' value is invalid."
    IDS_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE_ARGUMENTOUTOFRANGE, "Value is outside of acceptable range."
    IDS_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE_ARGUMENTOUTOFRANGE_NAMED, "'%s' value is outside of \
                                                acceptable range."
    IDS_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE_EXCEPTION, "Exception of type '%s' was thrown."
    IDS_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE_FILENOTFOUND, "Unable to find the specified file."
    IDS_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE_FILENOTFOUND_NAMED, "Unable to find '%s'."
    IDS_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE_IO, "I/O error occurred."
}
```

When I attempt to create a ja-JP.RC file I encounter a couple of problems.  First, I am asked to save the file as "unicode" - which when I inspect the file encoding via Save As it uses Codepage 65001 (Unicode UTF8 with signatures).  If I don't use this code page then I receive alerts regarding potential loss of data.

The second problem is that the file does not compile.  I receive the following error:

error RC2255: named STRINGTABLEs are not allowed

Here is my ja-JP.RC file:

```
#pragma once

#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h"

/* Exceptions */
STRINGTABLE
LANGUAGE LANG_JAPANESE, SUBLANG_JAPANESE_JAPAN
{
    IDS_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE_ARGUMENT, "値が無効です。"
    IDS_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE_ARGUMENT_NAMED, "「%s」値が無効です。"
    IDS_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE_ARGUMENTOUTOFRANGE, "値が許容範囲の外にある。"
    IDS_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE_ARGUMENTOUTOFRANGE_NAMED, "「%s」値が許容範囲の外にある。"
    IDS_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE_EXCEPTION, "種類「%s」の例外がスローされました。"
    IDS_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE_FILENOTFOUND, "指定されたファイルが見つかりません。"
    IDS_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE_FILENOTFOUND_NAMED, "「%s」を見つけることができません。"
    IDS_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE_IO, "入力/出力エラーが発生しました。"
}
```

As you can see in some of the Japanese strings I am using %s in order to pass in arguments.

How should I generate a "ja-JP" compliant RES file?

Comment: Hard to guess how to repro this.  But don't use utf-8, rc.exe is a cranky old sod and doesn't know how to handle it.  Use utf-16 instead, code page 1200 in the dialog.

Comment: Well, that did the job.  Thanks!  The RES compiles into the correct form (verified the strings using a ResEdit tool).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it uses Codepage 65001 (Unicode UTF8 with signatures)

I ought to document this mishap in a post, the error message is confounding enough to make anybody use an hour of two from their life.  Rc.exe is a stone-cold old Windows SDK tool that has not kept up with the times and is probably well past its still-maintainable stage.  First version I got is v1.1, dated April 17th, 1985.  It will soon celebrate its 30th birthday :)

It is not capable of properly parsing a utf-8 encoded file.  This *usually* gives confounding errors about not being able to find files, `error RC2135, file not found` is typical.  You found another failure mode, "named STRINGTABLEs are not allowed" does not exactly give a fantastic hint at the problem :)

You *must* save it as a utf-16 encoded file, the encoding that Windows internally uses for strings.  Pick Unicode (code page 1200) from the Save-As dialog, click the arrow on the Save button to select it.

Comment: In my scenario Visual Studio identified that the RC file must be saved in unicode, but used codepage 65001 (unicode UTF8 with signatures) as the default setting.  In short, don't rely on the default.  You can re-save an RC file through Save As - which gives you the opportunity to use a different encoding.  In my version of Visual Studio (2013) the save button has an arrow to the right of the "Save" label - you can use this to choose to save with a different encoding.